# Send a daily mailing list of 50,000 mails

Tags: php, smtp, mailing-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send 100.000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

I need to send a daily mail list of 50,000 mails from my php website.

What's the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** 
If this is new territory for you, I would recommend paying a little bit more and using a service like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor.

**Long Answer:** 
[How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: Doing it yourself, unless you know what you're doing, is a very good way to get your mail server onto blacklists...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly/3905805#3905805), and then [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296546/php-mass-mailing-25k-100k-lists). Long story short, don't try to do it yourself, use an external service.